# Android device square button exit app for react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Is there a way to exit react native app and exit all events when the device square button on the right side is pressed similar to Backhandler for the cancel button (triangle button).

[image]

Comment: In that transition-state between background and foreground?

Comment: you mean when the square button is pressed then you swipe the app to close it, yes

Comment: `AppState` supported by react-native (Android) ... has either Active or background state ... that inActive state only available for iOS
https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

Comment: ill will check this, thanks a lot!